# 405 Method Not Allowed with first rest API in legacy application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I have legacy web application(spring 4.2.*) which uses Front Controller design pattern(using dispatcher servlet) for view resolving.
I wanted to add my first Rest API
I am getting 405 Method now allowed

here is my rest controller code

```
    @RestController
    public class ProductCatalogResource {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/api", produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public String create(ProductLocation productLocation) {

        return "succcess";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "Welcome to RestTemplate Example.";
    }
}
```

when i make a post call to http://localhost:8090/api
i am getting

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL</body>

</html>
```

from debug logs i found below. i feel the second part of log saying that the URL mappings are empty. May be the legacy dispatcher servlet configuration overriding the Rest Resource registration? Any help to sort out the issue?

```
2020.06.19 04:30:18.656 ServerService Thread Pool -- 68 DEBUG 2 request handler methods found on class com.org.webservice.controller.ProductCatalogResource: {public java.lang.String com.org.webservice.controller.ProductCatalogResource.create(com.org.webservice.controller.ProductLocation)={[/api],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}, public java.lang.String com.org.webservice.controller.ProductCatalogResource.welcome()={[/]}}
2020.06.19 04:30:18.658 ServerService Thread Pool -- 68  INFO Mapped "{[/api],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.String com.org.webservice.controller.ProductCatalogResource.create(com.org.webservice.controller.ProductLocation)
2020.06.19 04:30:18.659 ServerService Thread Pool -- 68  INFO Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.org.webservice.controller.ProductCatalogResource.welcome()
.
.
.
2020.06.19 04:30:18.936 ServerService Thread Pool -- 68 DEBUG Rejected bean name 'productCatalogResource': no URL paths identified
```

[image]

**Update :**
The request mappings are overriden by URL mappings

Answer (score 0):

well first you have to watch that your are making a POST request in postman,
because by default it's set to GET.
i have tried your code and it's working fine.

[image: img1]

Comment: i suspect url mappings are overridden. i am using Postman and POST request. ideally the same dispatcher servlet is capable of serving rest calls?